# randomize span4 in twitter bootstrap2

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am loading a specific amount (6) of `.span4` in a random order when the browser is refreshed.

In bootstrap, all except the first `.span` come with a `margin-left` gutter. Therefore I needed to remove it (`margin-left`) from all `.span4`'s so that they would load properly into two lines.

As a result I have the `span4`'s not stretching to the full width of the `.container` and with no margin between each-one..

As the `.span`'s are loaded ramdomly I can don't know of any css solution to give the desired margin.. so what options do I have?

[LIVE VERSION HERE >>](http://33tpm.com/bs2/)

**UPDATE**
[Here is how I would like it to look (not function)>>](http://33tpm.com/bs2-ex/)

Is there any JS that could generate a margin around whatever `span4` that gets second and fifth place?

Comment: Can you draw a picture with the result that you expect?

Comment: $('.span4').css('margin-left','0');
Not 100% sure this is what you want

Comment: Do you want a margin on some spans but not others?

Answer (score 0):

You should group your `.span4` in `.row` [RTFM](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#gridSystem)

http://jsfiddle.net/nkHQP/

If you can't do that when generating html (server-side) for some reason, do the job with [jQuery.wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/)

Comment: doing this would mean that I manually control the rows right?